# Changing the Telerik MVC Grid columns dynamically on client-side

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I would like to show my table data in grid. The table has more than 50 columns. By default they are displayed fine but I need a way to hide/show columns which are not required on screen.

So is there any way to achieve this? I think right clicking on the header should show all headers in a list box, allowing selection of which columns we want, then refresh the grid.

Please let me know if Telerik supports this and, if so, how?

Answer (score 0):

No builtin feature available and this is one of many reasons why we are still thinking about other grids instead of telerik.

In the demo site there is a page where they show all the column names with checkboxes on top of the grid and you can check/uncheck to show/hide columns. see that sample source code, is simple to implement but still is custom code to add manually. I love the devexpress grid with customization popup and columns dragdrop from there but nothing like that for us in Telerik :-(

Comment: Thanks, but is there any open source project to achieve this ?